# what's the bug in that c# string handling?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Here is a sample HTML document that I am passing as MemoryStream in the code as given below

```
<h5>Sample Document </h5>
<h3> Present Tense </h3>

</p><p>The present tense is just as you have learned.  You take the dictionary form of a verb, drop the &#45796;, add the appropriate ending.

</p><p>&#47673;&#45796; - &#47673; + &#50612;&#50836; = &#47673;&#50612;&#50836; <br />
&#47560;&#49884;&#45796; - &#47560;&#49884; + &#50612;&#50836; - &#47560;&#49884;&#50612;&#50836; - &#47560;&#49492;&#50836;. <br />

</p><p>This tense is used to represent what happens in the present.  I eat. I drink.  It is a general term for the present.
```

The Below mentioned program contains three functions

- `Main`
- `ReadDocument`
- `TestByteOffSet`

Main function takes the above specifed HTML document as converts it to memoryStream and then passes it further to ReadDocument function which stores the result in a variable called docContent. Its a class level variable.

Then the main function takes a selected text using myRange.Text tries to find its index in the given document. Once the index is found its stored in intByteOffSet variable.

Now The third function TestByteOffSet tries to make sure that the Index stored in intByteOffSet is correct or not.

Here I am having issues when I try to get the string from byteOffSet, I do not receive the selected text.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MultiByteStringHandling
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] bit = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            MemoryStream Mr = new MemoryStream(bit);
            ReadDocument(Mr);

            mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange CompleteRange = 
                              _body.createTextRange().duplicate();
            int intByteOffset = 0;
            Regex reg = default(Regex);
          
            try
            {
                // Get all of the text that is in between HTML tags. 
                string regSearchText = myRange.htmlText;
                string strTemp = regSearchText + "\\s*";

                string strExp = ">(([^<])*?)" + strTemp + "(([^<])*?)<";
                string _cleanedSource = "";

                _cleanedSource = CompleteRange.htmlText;

                // Use regular expressions to find a collection of matches 
                //that match a certain pattern. 
                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(_cleanedSource, strExp,
                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    Int32 ret = default(Int32);
                    Int32 index = default(Int32);
                    string strMatch = m.Value;

                    foreach (Match m2 in Regex.Matches(strMatch, strTemp, 
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    {
                        // Increment counter when finding a match. 
                        intCount += 1;
                        // If counter matches occurrence number, return 
                        //source offset. 
                        if (intCount == OccurenceNo)
                        {
                            //Source offset is the index of the overall 
                            //match + index innerText Match. 

                            int intCharOffset = m.Index + m2.Index;
                            System.Text.UTF8Encoding d = new        
                                        System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                            // Using the SourceText will give an accurate 
                            //byte offset. 
                           intByteOffset = d.GetBytes(
                          _cleanedSource.Substring(0, intCharOffset)).Length;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
               
            }
        }

    private void ReadDocument(Stream sD)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(ms);
        bool hasMore = true;
        sD.Position = 0;
        using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(sD))
        {
            while (hasMore)
            {
                byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(8192);
                hasMore = buffer.Length > 0;
                if (hasMore)
                {
                    bw.Write(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
        byte[] docBuffer = ms.GetBuffer();
        docContent = new byte[docBuffer.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(docBuffer, docContent, docBuffer.Length);
    }
    private bool TestByteOffset(TransparencyItemType transparency)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = default(System.Text.UTF8Encoding);
        string byteOffsetLabel = null;
        Int32 iLength = default(Int32);
        Int32 offset = default(Int32);

        if (((transparency.Label == null) == false))
        {
            iLength = Convert.ToInt32(transparency.Label.IEOffset.Length);
            offset = Convert.ToInt32(transparency.Label.IEOffset.Offset);
        }
        else if (((transparency.Value == null) == false))
        {
            if(transparency.Value.ByteOffset!=null)
            {
                if (transparency.Value.ByteOffset.Offset != -1)
                {
                    iLength = Convert.ToInt32(transparency.Value.ByteOffset.Length);
                    offset = Convert.ToInt32(transparency.Value.ByteOffset.Offset);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: So, you get a Stream representing the file, read it into a byte array, create a new stream from the byte array, pass that stream to ReadDocument, which will make it into a byte array. Why not simply pass the first FileStream to ReadDocument. Or better yet, read the FileStream contents into a string, and operate on that string?

Comment: I understand your point but I guess I am doing the same thing  though not in proper mannner.

Comment: Start by removing the empty `catch` that you have. You can just put a `throw;` in it to rethrow the exception.

The empty catch will silently swallow any exception, which means that you have no idea if the code is working or not, and you have no clue to where a problem might occur or why.

Comment: You could even put error logging in the catch block if you need subsequent operations to be tried. (Though I'm not sure why that would be the case here... It's just often overlooked by my peers at work... Thankfully it usually gets caught before deployment.)

Answer (score 0):

The source that is posted does not seem to be complete. TestByteOffset is never called. FileName, mshtml, _body, myRange, intCount, and OccurenceNo are not defined. docContent is never referenced in Main, nor is any other variable that might contain the original text (fs, br, bit, or Mr). CompleteRange would seem to have to contain the text, but it cannot get it unless _body can provide it, and _body is not defined.

Please check to be sure the code you post is complete and can be compiled.

It would be a lot easier to debug the code if it did not have so much unnecessary manipulation (as was mentioned by Fredrik Mörk). It is not just a matter of using the proper manner; if the code is hard to understand, it is that much harder to debug.